# Script error accessing a SP site when same specs as all other users who can access the site are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility, angularjs

I'm working with a SharePoint site. The site contains AngularJs script. All of the users who has access to can access it using either Chrome or IE11. One user he is getting "Angular Undefined" error even though he is using IE11. He can't access the site by using chrome also. His developer tools are grayed out in chrome. I don't know why this is happening.